# Batch Script SET /p entering special spanish characters

Tags: variables, batch-file, set

I obtain different results depending on how I set my variable

Case 1

```
@echo off
set TITLE=Cañete
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "line=<docTitle><text>%TITLE%</text></docTitle>"
( echo !line! ) > test1.txt
```

Case 2

```
set /P TITLE=     ( I introduce here the same word Cañete )
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
set "line=<docTitle><text>%TITLE%</text></docTitle>" 
( echo !line! ) > test2.txt
```

I obtain in test1.txt the correct text:

```
<docTitle><text>Cañete</text></docTitle>
```

In in test2.txt, I obtain the wrong txt:

```
<docTitle><text>ca¤ete</text></docTitle>
```

My question: How can I obtain in case 2 the correct

```
<docTitle><text>Cañete</text></docTitle>
```

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Apply the CHCP command to the second code:

```
SET /P TITLE=     ( I introduce here the same word Cañete )
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
CHCP 1252 > NUL
SET "line=<docTitle><text>%TITLE%</text></docTitle>" 
( 
    ECHO !line! 
) > test2.txt
CHCP 850 > NUL
```

I hope that I have helped.